# When should `Sent` be used over `SentInput` in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

The [Autohotkey documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) writes:

> SendInput is generally the preferred method to send keystrokes and mouse clicks because of its superior speed and reliability. Under most conditions, SendInput is nearly instantaneous, even when sending long strings. Since SendInput is so fast, it is also more reliable because there is less opportunity for some other window to pop up unexpectedly and intercept the keystrokes. Reliability is further improved by the fact that anything the user types during a SendInput is postponed until afterward.

If `SendInput` is generally preferred, what are the use cases where `sent` is better in ahk? When does `Sent` win the `Sent` vs. `SentInput` decision?

Comment: In my experience, SendInput is often too fast and sensitive and can have unwanted results in some programs if you don't add some Sleep afterwards.

Comment: by default, `send` is the same as `sendEvent`. See  https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm . Not sure if still, but some time ago, the template for new default AHK-scripts had the line `sendMode, Input` in their auto-execution head section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use `SendInput`, as I like the nearly instantaneous input. However I have encountered a few practical limitations:

- Some applications like games do not like such fast key strokes because there may be rules against botting.
- Some applications can't handle receiving keystrokes that fast and they just get bogged down.
- I had an application that allowed pressing tab to move the cursor between fields.

  - When tabbing into a field the application needed time to acknowledge the arrival of the cursor before it would accept any input. The `SendInput` command was just to fast for this and frequently lead to mixed results
  - Pressing tab multiple times was also problematic, and frequently some tabs would be missed by the application and the cursor would end on an unexpected field.
- `SendInput` is too fast to replay something for debugging. For example when I want to watch how the text is being inserted into fields on very complex forms.
- In theory with `Send` you could insert a blob of text and randomly press and hold the shift button to increase entropy while the characters were being typed. Arguably I can't think of why this would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider switching between `SendPlay` and `SendInput` only if you have problems with current setup. SendInput cause problems if you type while a long macro was activated. Your commands might be mixed with macro causing undesired behavior. Tutorial says that `SendPlay` is "not supported in older games", but I never had problems with that. Someone might comment "you haven't used AHK enough". Well, maybe.

Also, before switching from SendPlay to SendInput you should try to divide your macro into two. For instance, "save control group, do stuff, recall control group" fails in Starcraft2. Splitting it into `Send "save control group, do stuff"; Sleep 10; Send "recall control group";` works.